# Scala implicit resolution for type (in)equality

Tags: scala, overloading, implicit, overload-resolution

The following code

```scala
import shapeless._ // =:!=

class G[T1] {
  def as[T2](implicit ev: T1 =:= T2): Unit = ???

  def as[T2](implicit ev: T1 =:!= T2): Unit = ???
}

val g = new G[Int]

g.as[Int]
```

results in the following compilation error:

```
ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method as in class G of type (implicit ev: Int =:!= Int): Unit
and  method as in class G of type (implicit ev: Int =:= Int): Unit
match expected type ?
    g.as[Int]
```

If we leave `G` only with one of the `as` methods, everything works as expected (both for type equality and inequality). Why does the compiler report this error message?

Comment: We should look at the rules of overloading resolution https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution and how it plays with implicit resolution https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/07-implicits.html A workaround is a typeclass https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/pqXuNY7VQSCiBpxMvxEWbw/1 In Scala 3 behavior is the same https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/pqXuNY7VQSCiBpxMvxEWbw/2

Comment: @DmytroMitin thank you. I am additionally dealing with existential type, and then the trick does not work any more: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/egnwOl2lSuuLmKb8FbjCcA

Comment: Well, this is natural, isn't it? Abstract `T1` is different from `Int`, `String` so it's `notEqual` case both times. https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DmytroMitin/pqXuNY7VQSCiBpxMvxEWbw/4